# How can I interpret the IRFs in the VAR models?

Tags: vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I am new to VAR, and I got confused about how I can interpret the IRFs in my research. In fact, I am analysing if there is any interplay between Twitter, Telegram, and Instagram in Iran. I have collected data, classified all datasets, and conducted standard VAR using EViews 12. However, I am not sure if my interpretation of the output is correct. There are some examples of IRFs below.
[image]

In the chart above, I am not sure if it is interpretable at all because the confidence interval bands are under the zero line. Moreover, does it mean that Instagram affected Twitter negatively (meaning a sudden increase on Insta leads to a decrease on Twitter?), or does it mean that Twitter affected Insta?
Another example:
[image]

I am wondering if you could help with interpreting these IRFs. Also, if you know any resources explaining how IRFs can be analyzed, I would appreciate it if you could introduce them.

Comment: It looks like your VAR model is unstable. This is because the IRFs are not converging back to zero. This probably indicates that the variables you used in VAR are non-stationary. You should check for stationarity and order of integration of your variables. It would also be a good idea to check for cointegration and consider VECM in the presence of cointegration.